# Creating JSON array in Go

Tags: arrays, json, go

How do I construct and send a JSON array with Go?

For example:

```
{ myArray: ["one", "two", "three"] }
```

At the moment the closest I can get it sending JSON down to the browser as a string like this:

```
{ myArrayString: '["once", "two", "three"]' }
```

Which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite *straightforward* as **@swoogan** comments:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type myJSON struct {
    Array []string
}

func main() {
    jsondat := &myJSON{Array: []string{"one", "two", "three"}}
    encjson, _ := json.Marshal(jsondat)
    fmt.Println(string(encjson))
}
```

Demo avaliable [here](https://play.golang.org/p/PI21OMmdo1).

Answer (score 2):

You need to `import "encoding/json"` and then use `json.Marshal` with your structure.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Marshal